# Can you wield a a typical shield and Aegis of the Raven Queen at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class, shield

I know that you can only hold one shield at a time but the description of the Aegis of the Raven says that its plus magic bonus to AC stacks up with the current pluses from a shield that is currently used. This description about bonuses does not make sense if you can't wield both shields at the same time.

Here is the description:

> While holding this shield, you have a +3 bonus to AC. This bonus is in addition to the shield's normal bonus to AC.

Comment: Related: "[Can you benefit from two different magical shields?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124036)"

Answer (score 22):

The Aegis of the Raven Queen states:

> While holding this shield, you have a +3 bonus to AC. This bonus is in addition to the shield's normal bonus to AC.

That's your normal shield bonus of +2 for using a shield, plus another +3 from that particular shield's magic, for a total of +5.  You don't have to use a second shield, nor should you.

You can wield two shields at once, but only the better one would apply to your AC, so there's usually no point in wielding twin shields. The relevant rule in the shield description simply says (emphasis mine):

> You can **benefit** from only one shield at a time.

Comment: In a previous edition (or sidedition?) of the game, there were surprisingly effective "shield bash" builds that would dual-wield shields, using a two-weapon combat style with spiked or enchanted shields.  Which is generally hilarious to think about.  Still couldn't get the AC bonus from both shields at once, though.

Comment: "there's usually no point in wielding twin shields" Under RAW, is there ever a time when there's a point or are you just being cautious in your wording?

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman if you are expecting something to take out one of your shields...

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman if there is a plot reason to wield two shields, eg. a challenge/dare/bet, a magical barrier requiring two shields as key, acting in a play...

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman I generally approach d20 system questions as if I don't ever know half of what can be done.  5e particularly I'm only an "expert" in the core rules.  I would not be remotely surprised if there were an Unearthed Arcana Dwarf-only Fighter Specialization or Eberron Warforged Barbarian subtype that dual-wields shields to significant effect.

Comment: @gatherer818 Besides, even if there isn’t something right now, it is conceivable so at some point someone will write magic items, feats or a subclass that dual wields shields.

Comment: To state it even more concisely: when it says "the shield", it means the Aegis of the Raven Queen (which is a shield) and not some other shield.